# how to navigate to a file.html in Isolated Storage using javascript - Windows Phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone, visual-studio-cordova

In my Cordova/Phonegap hybrid app, I copied the file page1.html to my app Isolated Storage using C#.

I can see my file with WP power Tools.

How can I navigate from my html page to page1.html using javascript?

Thanks